# Yii1 - use array in the GridView column and push value in that array

Tags: yii, yii1.x

I have following arrays outside **GridView**:

```
$companyIDs = [];
$companyNames = [];
```

And following column:

```
'company_id' => [
        'name' => 'company_id',
        'header' => 'Client',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => function ($data, $row) use($companyIDs, $companyNames) {
            array_push($companyIDs, $data->company_id);
            var_dump('<pre>', $companyIDs, '</pre>');
            return $data->company->company_name;
        },
    ],
```

At the moment the array is destroyed each time and only contains one value. Is there a way to push values to the array?

Comment: Use reference: `use (&$companyIDs, &$companyNames)`.

Answer (score -1):

What if you push your items into the array before the Gridview?